# Displaying an error message in a Do..While loop in java

Tags: java, loops, message, do-while

I'm trying to get my Do..While loop to display an error message to why it is re-asking for the user input again. This is my code for it:

```
do {
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the floor you are on: ");
    current_Floor = in.nextInt();   
}

// Loop until user input is equal to or less than the maximum floors
while( current_Floor > MAX_FLOORS );{
    System.out.println("Please enter a floor which is less than 8");
}
```

The problem with this code is that the "Error" message which i've added appears after a correct user input has been entered, when I need it to display before the user input is added in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formatting is all screwy, which is probably what's confusing you. The `;` at the end of your `while` **ends** the `do-while`. The braces after that, containing the "error" statement, are just a static set of braces: they're not associated with your loop in any way.

If you format your code more legibly, it looks like this, which makes it clear that your "less than 8" message is placed incorrectly, and will always be printed, once you exit the loop.

```
do {
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the floor you are on: ");
    current_Floor = in.nextInt();   
} while( current_Floor > MAX_FLOORS );

{ // Useless braces!
    System.out.println("Please enter a floor which is less than 8");
} // Useless braces!
```

---

If you want to loop until some condition is met while informing the user of "failed" iterations, the usual idiom is generally to loop forever, and then `break` when your condition is met:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the floor you are on: ");
    current_Floor = in.nextInt();   
    if (current_Floor <= MAX_FLOORS) {
        break;
    }

    // This prints only if the user entered a bad number.
    System.out.println("Please enter a floor which is less than 8");
}
```

Alternately, you can "extract" the first iteration of the loop, and then use a conventional `while` loop (or `do-while` if you're really committed to that structure for some reason) to ensure that the input is acceptable. Personally, I find the previous version a little cleaner, but that's really just down to personal preference and coding style.

```
// Initial input
System.out.println("\nPlease enter the floor you are on: ");
current_Floor = in.nextInt();

// Loop until the input is acceptable
while (current_Floor > MAX_FLOORS) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a floor which is less than 8");
    current_Floor = in.nextInt();   
}
```

---

As an aside, it's kind of nasty to be referring to `MAX_FLOORS` in the code, while hard-coding the magic number `8` into your error message: it would be better to use some [string formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) to tell the user what the actual maximum floor number is.

```
System.out.println(String.format("Please enter a floor which is less than %d", MAX_FLOORS+1));
```

---

As another aside, your naming scheme is kind of weird: by convention, most variable names in Java should use camelCase, without underscores, e.g. `currentFloor`. Your `MAX_FLOORS` is okay though, since it seems to be a static/enum-like variable, which *do* conventionally use capslock with underscores.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks dude, i've only been learning java for about 20 weeks so still a beginner with it, thanks for the advise

Answer (score 2):

Java do while syntax is as follows:

```
do {
    //block of code to execute
} while([some boolean condition]);
```

Comment: So? OP is already following this structure.

Comment: Yes...but she or he also has MORE than this...hoping this will nudge him/her in the right direction without just giving the answer away.

Answer (score 1):

Please look on Flow chart of a `do-while` loop:

[image]

And [Read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `do-while` loops work in Java. I'd recommend sticking with a `while` loop since your initial pass is a little different from each subsequent one.

```
System.out.println("Please enter a floor which is less than 8");
current_Floor = in.nextInt();

while (current_Floor > MAX_FLOORS) {
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the floor you are on: ");
    current_Floor = in.nextInt();    
}
```

Here you prompt the user for an input. If it's invalid, you enter the loop where you display the error message and prompt them again. This will continue until the user behaves.

Comment: This structure is not a `do-while`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are misusing the do-while loop.

```
do{
    ...STUFF...
}while( $CONDITION );
...MORE STUFF...
```

Works like this

1. do STUFF
2. calculate condition
3. if CONDITION is true, go to 1, if not go to 4
4. do MORE STUFF

In you case, STUFF is "ask the user for a floor", the condition is "is the floor the user selected greater than the max floor?", and MORE STUFF is "Ask the user to enter a floor less 8".

What you do is probably have the CONDITION be keep asking until a valid floor is selected, and have the check in an if statement inside the do-while loop.

Answer (score -2):

The "do while" isn't the best type of loop to use here, because you need to check the condition in the middle of the repeated part, not at the end.  It's possible to do this with "do while", but you end up checking the condition twice.

In order not to repeat code, there's a good alternative.  The first line means "loop forever", but it will actually just loop until the "break" is encountered, which happens when the user enters correct input.

```
for(;;) {
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the floor you are on: ");
    current_Floor = in.nextInt();   
    if (current_Floor <= MAX_FLOORS) {
        break;
    }

    System.out.println("Please enter a floor which is less than 8");
}
```

Comment: Even if the for loop is better, when a new programmer is learning, they need to know how to program a do-while loop.

Comment: The question says "any ideas".  It doesn't say "I have to use a do-while" loop.  I answered the question.

Comment: You may have a point.  I re-read the question and to me "any ideas" is referring as to why it is not working and not as to how to get it to work some other way

Comment: Whether or not they *need* to use a do-while is sort of beyond the point.  They obviously have a large misconception and it's worth addressing.  Moreover, a simple `while` loop (with the opposite of the conditional in your `if` statement) is better than the bad practice of using an infinite `for` loop.

Comment: @gravityplanx Says who?  Who calls this a "bad practice"?  This is a good practice for when the condition needs to be checked in the middle of the loop, rather than the beginning or the end.  Any other way requires checking the condition twice.  THAT would be a poor practice, because a future maintainer might inadvertently change one check but not the other.

Comment: @David Wallace:  You do not need to check it twice.  It can be done in a single while loop, with no additional checks:  `[initial value prompt/get]; while([value is unsatisfactory]){ [prompt/get replacement value] }`

Comment: @gravityplanx No, the user wants "Please enter the floor you are on" on every iteration.  Your way will give them something different.

Comment: @David Wallace:  ... you could rewrite that single line within the while loop...  It's more important to make code Readable and Efficient during runtime than it is to make code contain the fewest number of possible lines.

Comment: I wasn't particularly bothered which method is used, just wanted a working output, and that seems to work great so thanks, however I will  be sticking to the While method which someone else has provided a better solution to.

Comment: @gravityplanx Who's trying to write code with the fewest number of lines?  Not I!  I agree completely about readability.  I am advocating not duplicating a condition.  You want to duplicate either the condition itself, or the line that shows the error.  I don't think you have fully thought this through.  You could probably learn something from the second grey box in Henry Keiter's answer here.  He explains differently from me why to meet the OP's requirements, the best solution is to have an "endless" loop, with a break in the middle.